# Launch Apache 2.2 on static IP

Tags: oracle, apache, static, ip

Is there any way to launch Apache server on my laptop with static IP address?
I need a remote access through web-interface to a local Oracle database from the internet.

Right now I have Zend Core installed which allowes me to connect to the database but I don't know how to make it from the internet.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dynamic DNS server (no-ip, dyndns) to get a dynamic IP address mapped to a constant domain name (and updated automatically).

Answer (score 0):

Apache doesn't assign IP addresses, your ISP does.

Comment: I know. I just said that I have a static IP to describe my situation somehow :)

Comment: Basic router configuration has nothing to do with programming and would be better posted elsewhere.